# NSUnknownKeyException error when running my app

Tags: objective-c, macos

this is my first time to try write an app and i face this error. i try to look what is the problem but i can't find it. and my app do not show me nothing.

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x13c9022 0x155acd6 0x13c8ee1 0x9c1022 0x932f6b 0x932edb 0x94dd50 0x23571a 0x13cadea 0x13347f1 0x23426e
>   0x235eb7 0x12ce1 0x12ff8 0x1217f 0x21183 0x21c38 0x15634 0x12b3ef5
>   0x139d195 0x1301ff2 0x13008da 0x12ffd84 0x12ffc9b 0x11c65 0x13626
>   0x2a22 0x2995) terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

here a link to see my screen:

Comment: you should modify your question to show the LINK to the screen and even better, show the lines of code that are throwing the exception (use the debugger to step through your code to get to that point).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with your nib file. Hard to tell for sure since there's not code, but make sure that the "File's owner" property in all your nib files (probably `MainMenu.xib` if the error occurs on application launch) and look in the identity inspector. Make sure that the type of class you're trying to instantiate is actually a class that has a `view` property.